Can I include pdf (using pdfpages pack) and automatically get the number of the inserted pdf
I make long technical (building engineering) documentation.
In those docs, the standard is to explain stuff in the main doc and put a reference to a detailed calculation at the end.
So I would like to know if I can do this...
\section{roofs}

The roof is 5 metres large per 30 metres long and the wind blablabla...

Detail is provided in include X.

\includepdf[pages=-]{extracts/roof.pdf}

\section{walls}

Walls are 20 cm concrete plates.

Calculations are provided as extract Y.

\includepdf[pages=-]{extracts/walls.pdf}


And the extracts will be included in the respective order, and then latex will replace X and Y by the respective numbers (just like it does with labels) by virtue of a command or reference that I will place here.
Edit to forbid confusion on renumbering of includes.

No, the external documents are made using other softwares (structural or even custom and macro excel sheets)

I am not to extract info, I am just to include the whole pdf as an include at the end of the file. (word "extract" was maybe not the best choice here, acknowledged)

Any page numbers of such printed on the original will show up on the copy.  You could add information manually ond ovelap the image.

Ok, now I'm confused. Which X should latex replace? The The roof is X metres large  or the Detail is provided in extract X.?

I am really, really sorry. Yes that was bad. Correcting.
The X to replace is "Detail is provided in include X"

Ahhhh! This makes it a completely different question :) You can use pdfpages to add labels to the includes files and the use the usual \ref to access them. (I'll clean up my comments above)

Where should the X and Y come from? How can the reader know what you mean with it?

That's the whole point, I want latex to automate that so that I don't have to work 10 minute at the end of each writing to renumber it.

Here is an example that gathers all attachments and inserts them at the very end of your document. References are available through option addtotoc.
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\tl_new:N\pdfpages_attachments
\NewDocumentCommand\attach{ mmm }{
  \tl_put_right:Nn\pdfpages_attachments{
    \includepdf[
      pages=1-3,
      pagecommand={},
      addtotoc={1, section, 1, #1, #3}
    ]{#2}}
}
\NewDocumentCommand\outputAttachments{}{
  \tl_use:N\pdfpages_attachments
}
\NewDocumentCommand\refAttachment{m}{
  \hyperref[#1]{\autoref*{#1} (\nameref*{#1})}
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\pagestyle{headings}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
%\newpage

\section{Roof}
\lipsum[1-4]

See \refAttachment{sec:att-roof}, page \pageref{sec:att-roof}.
\attach{Calculation Roof}{example-image-a4-numbered.pdf}{sec:att-roof}

\section{Wall}
\lipsum[1-4]

See \refAttachment{sec:att-wall}, page \pageref{sec:att-wall}.
\attach{Calculation Wall}{example-image-a4-numbered.pdf}{sec:att-wall}

\appendix
\outputAttachments
\end{document}


Hej, that is awesome actually and exactly what I want, thank you.
One minor question though : is there a way I replace the word "appendix" to something else (because that word is different in the language I work in : called "bilag" )

Switch the language. E.g. load \usepackage[danish]{babel} before hyperref.
